# Is there a written definition for line count of a text file?

Tags: linux, file-management, newlines

Is there a definition or definitions for line count of a file?

A command like `wc -l data.txt` would only count the amount of newline characters.
But this ignores scenarios such as where contents are `ABBA\nCD EOF`, which would be displayed on 2 lines in many text based editors but only counted as 1 line in wc.

I am asking for a written definition of line count.

Comment: If you have a specific definition in mind ("non-empty content after the last \n and before EOF counts as a line"), you need to write down your definition... there is no "standard" one.

Comment: I am not asking for a standard definition. I am asking for any definition written down on text before my question. If there are multiple contradicting ones, then those are all proper answers. How can I improve this question?

Comment: If you know a single definition and there are no other answers, then I can aprove that. This question would then help anyone else wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of line count depends on what you define as the line break. Common values are `\r\n`, `\n`, or `\r` (Macs before Mac OS X, among others).

Some file formats have a defined line break which does not depend on the system, e.g. [CSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) uses `\r\n`.

More extensive information is available on Wikipedia: [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).